# Pandas read_csv() gives DtypeWarning

Tags: python, pandas

I created a `.csv` file from a dataframe as below:

```
df.to_csv('partial.csv', sep=',')
```

Datatypes in the dataframe

`df.dtypes` gives:

```
Contact_ID      int64
Src_Sys_Cd     object
First_Name     object
Last_Name      object
Src_Sys_Key    object
Full_Name      object
Office_No      object
Mobile         object
Email          object
dtype: object
```

When I try to read the newly created `.csv` file using `read_csv`it gives me error:

```
new_df =  pd.read_csv('partial.csv')
```

> DtypeWarning: Columns (5) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on
>   import or set low_memory=False.   interactivity=interactivity,
>   compiler=compiler, result=result)

How can I avoid this error? Is this error coming up because I did something wrong while `to_csv` or `read_csv` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please give the below a shot. It might work well,

```py
new_df = pd.read_csv('partial.csv', low_memory=False)
```

Comment: What does `low_memory = False` do?

Comment: @TomJMuthirenthi from the documentation  `Internally process the file in chunks, resulting in lower memory use while parsing, but possibly mixed type inference. To ensure no mixed types either set False, or specify the type with the dtype parameter. Note that the entire file is read into a single DataFrame regardless, use the chunksize or iterator parameter to return the data in chunks. (Only valid with C parser) `

Answer (score 5):

What are the data types of your original columns?
You can try specifying the data types in read_csv by putting an argument dtype:

```
types = {‘your_col_name01’: your_dtype01, ‘your_col_name02’: your_dtype02}
new_df = pd.read_csv('partial.csv', dtype=types)
```

Comment: I have added the datatypes in the question

Answer (score 5):

```
pd.read_csv('input.csv', engine='python')
```

does the trick for me.